# Unity Vuforia Project - Xcode build issue

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

Our AR-App using Unity 2019.4.2f1 and Vuforia Engine AR 9.5.4 is running into an issue when building the application in Xcode (Version 14.2)

The error we are running into is:

[image: Error]

We have tried to fix the problem by changing the permissions of the ARFoundationDriver.framework file but it didn't help. We also tried a newer Unity version with no success either.

Does anyone know anything about this error and how to fix it?